Convert raw text to QA-format data
I am looking for options to convert raw text (pdf, txt, etc...) into QA-format data that can be used to finetune a chat-based LLM. So far I have found augmentoolkit which looks very promising. I wonder whether there are other tools out there that can do something similar?


I wonder whether there are other tools out there that can do something similar?

One could prompt  some LLM to generate QA pairs, e.g. as done in this paper:

For Adobe Photoshop, GPT-4 initially generated question-answer pairs
based on the web pages, which are subsequently
reviewed and corrected by product experts to guarantee accuracy and relevance to the question and
the answer.

